# How to parse XML grouped by specific tag id

Tags: python, xml, dataframe

I have the following xml file and I will like to structure it group it by Table Id.

```
xml = """
 <Tables Count="19">
    <Table Id="1" >
      <Data>
        <Cell>
          <Brush/>
          <Text>AA</Text>
          <Text>BB</Text>
         </Cell>
       </Data>
    </Table>

    <Table Id="2" >
      <Data>
        <Cell>
          <Brush/>
          <Text>CC</Text>
          <Text>DD</Text>
         </Cell>
       </Data>
    </Table>
</Tables>
"""
```

I would like to parse it and get something like this.

[image]

I have tried something below but couldn't figure out it.

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.fromstring(xml)

users = {}
for user in tree.xpath("//Tables"):
    name = user.xpath("Table")[0].text
    users[name] = []
    for group in user.xpath("Data/Cell/Text"):
        users[name].append(group.text)

print (users)
```

Is that possible to get the above result? if so, could anyone help me to do this? I really appreciate your effort.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "couldn't figure it out"?

Comment: When I try it execute the above piece of code I got the following error: ```XMLSyntaxError: Start tag expected, '<' not found, line 1, column 1```.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your `xpath` queries to:

```
from lxml import etree

tree = etree.fromstring(xml)

users = {}
for user in tree.xpath("//Tables/Table"):
#                                ^^^
    name = user.attrib['Id']
    users[name] = []
    for group in user.xpath(".//Data/Cell/Text"):
    #                        ^^^
        users[name].append(group.text)

print (users)
```

...and use the `attrib` dictionary.
This yields for your string:

```
{'1': ['AA', 'BB'], '2': ['CC', 'DD']}
```

---

If you're into "one-liners", you could even do:

```
users = {name: [group.text for group in user.xpath(".//Data/Cell/Text")]
         for user in tree.xpath("//Tables/Table")
         for name in [user.attrib["Id"]]}
```

Comment: Thank you, Jan. That is perfect. Next, I will try to create a data frame like the above table. If it isn't working, I will come back for your help.